# How to seperate the returned record of ADODB and store in a php variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql, adodb

Here is my code segment:

```
 $r = $db->Execute('Select * from data');
 while(!$r->EOF){
 print_r($r-fields);
 $r->MoveNext();
 }
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => 8373 [1] => 8372 [2] => 8027 [3] => 406 [4] => 1 [5] => [6] => |host_description| LiveConnections [7] => LiveConnections [8] => /liveconnections_8027.rrd [9] => [10] => on [11] => [12] => 60 [13] => )
```

I would like to store the 8th field "liveconnections_8027.rrd" to a variable `$path`how can i do that?

Comment: i have tried $path = $r[8] but it isn't work

Comment: `$path = $r->fields[8]` ?

Comment: Rikesh it isn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you use Execute for a query which should return something. Try following:

```
$r = $db->GetAll('SELECT * FROM data');
```

Then you can just access it via `$path = $r[8]`. Execute is usually used in AdoDB for queries like `DELETE` or `INSERT`, but not for `SELECT`